Is there any error in my code, why am I getting a 401 error with the Experian API?
So, I am creating a web application, this is my first time using an API and connecting to an external web server, I am good at Python and creating scripts, but this was the first step to make sure I can get data, then build the UX and all the other function, but this issue is stopping me. I would rather use Python than JSON is it even possible?
import requests
import json
import time


# Configuration
CLIENT_ID = "CODE"
CLIENT_SECRET = "CODE"
USERNAME = "USERNAME"
PASSWORD = "PASSWORD"
BASE_URL = "https://sandbox-us-api.experian.com"

# Global variables to store tokens
access_token = None
refresh_token = None

def request_access_token():
    global access_token, refresh_token
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/oauth2/v1/token"
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    data = {
        "username": USERNAME,
        "password": PASSWORD,
        "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET,
        "grant_type": "password"
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

    if response.status_code == 200:
        tokens = response.json()
        access_token = tokens.get("access_token")
        refresh_token = tokens.get("refresh_token")
        print("Access Token:", access_token)
        print("Refresh Token:", refresh_token)
    else:
        print("Failed to get access token. Status code:", response.status_code)
        print("Response:", response.json())

def refresh_access_token():
    global access_token, refresh_token
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/oauth2/v1/token"
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    data = {
        "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET,
        "grant_type": "refresh_token",
        "refresh_token": refresh_token
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

    if response.status_code == 200:
        tokens = response.json()
        access_token = tokens.get("access_token")
        refresh_token = tokens.get("refresh_token")
        print("New Access Token:", access_token)
        print("New Refresh Token:", refresh_token)
    else:
        print("Failed to refresh token. Status code:", response.status_code)
        print("Response:", response.json())

def revoke_token(token):
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/oauth2/v1/revokeToken"
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    data = {
        "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET,
        "token": token
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Token successfully revoked.")
    else:
        print("Failed to revoke token. Status code:", response.status_code)
        print("Response:", response.json())

def make_api_call():
    global access_token
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/business/score/v2/directors"
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("API response:", response.json())
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch data. Status code:", response.status_code)
        print("Response:", response.json())

# Main workflow
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Step 1: Request Access Token
    request_access_token()

    # Simulate waiting for token expiration
    time.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds (in real use, wait until token is about to expire)

    # Step 2: Use Bearer Token
    make_api_call()

    # Step 3: Refresh Access Token
    refresh_access_token()

    # Step 4: Revoke Token
    revoke_token(access_token)




Out come :
enter image description here
https://developer.experian.com/get-started#step-1
https://developer.experian.com/products/us/businesses/businesses-api-docs
I used chat GPT, and now I am here on stack over flow.

this have nothing to do with the question but I suggest you hide any personal information like secret, email and password in your code before post on the internet.

Noted and Fixed Appreciate it !

You should remove that password ASAP as it's still visible in the history

Change your email password NOW if you’ve not done it already.  It might have already been ‘hacked’, albeit legitimately as you’ve given us the credentials. Hopefully you’re using a different password(?)

This is actually a printed log in the console.
else:
    print("Failed to get access token. Status code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response:", response.json())

It looks like you don't have permissions to access the resource or your credentials are incorrect. First step is check out credentials.
